# Bokeh manual stack bar plot missing level in display

Tags: bokeh

I try to manually create a stacked bar plot in bokeh as I can do in matplotlib. The code works but the output plot shows some issues I cannot explain or solve. To me, it seems like the error always appear at the second level, no matter if I have two levels (i.e. number of bars) or three levels stacked. In the three levels plot, the color is miss matched due to the missing second level.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
import numpy as np
output_notebook()

test_data = {
    'index' : np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
    'a' : np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]),
    'b' : np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10]),
    'c' : np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
}
s = ColumnDataSource(test_data)

alpha_lst = [1, 0.5, 0.1]
keys = list(s.data.keys())[1:-1]    # stack 2 levels/bars
# keys = list(s.data.keys())[1:]    # stack 3 levels/bars
w_bar = 0.9
level = 0  

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=360)
for j in range(len(keys)):
    p.vbar(x=s.data['index'], bottom=level,
           top=level+s.data[keys[j]], width=w_bar, color='#43a2ca',
           line_color='#3A5785', fill_alpha=alpha_lst[j], legend_label=keys[j])
    level += s.data[keys[j]]
p.legend.location = 'top_left'

show(p)
```

**Stacked Bar 2 Levels**:

[image: stacked bar 2 levels]

**Stacked Bar 3 Levels**:

[image: stacked bar 3 levels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons why `level += s.data[keys[j]]` is bad:

1. You change the variable type from `int` to `numpy.array`. I maaaaybe OK in this case, but generally it makes it harder to make sense of and debug later on
2. After it becomes an array (i.e. at the end of the very first loop iteration), the next execution of that line mutates the array *in place*. Meaning, the `VBar` that was created by the second call to `p.vbar` now has `bottom` with the same value as `top`.

It's up to you how (and whether) you fix #1. And to fix #2, which will solve your main problem, just replace `level += s.data[keys[j]]` with `level = level + s.data[keys[j]]`.